# Error configuring OracleDb and Nodejs connection

Tags: node.js, oracle, protractor

Below error received while configuring OracleDB with NodeJS. I have downloaded Oracle Instant Client and set the `PATH ,ORACLE_PATH, OCI_INC_DIR, OCI_LIB_DIR`

```
E/launcher - Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client li
brary: "The specified module could not be found". See https://oracle.github.io/o
dpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help
```

Comment: it is not related to protractor

Comment: You either have the wrong Instant Client (did you accidentally install the 32-bit version?); or didn't follow the instructions about the VS Redistributable; or haven't set PATH properly; or haven't restarted a terminal window since you set PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Christopher issue was i did not have basic and SDK instant client library in same folder. I created a folder for Oracle--> Instantclient and added all the files inside that.
Later defined the PATH in environmental variable.

Below are the instantclient used. We need both of them to connect to oracle DB.

instantclient-sdk-windows.x64-18.5.0.0.0dbru

instantclient-basiclite-windows.x64-18.5.0.0.0dbru